# Reducing font glyphs to create webfonts with only latin characters?

Tags: fonts, character, filesize, glyph, latin

How can I take a font file and remove all glyphs that are not standard latin characters (A-Z, 0-9, special characters, etc)?

For example I downloaded the [FreeSans font from GNU FreeFont](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/freefont/), but it contains thousands of characters from all languages. I want to strip all that extra filesize in order to convert it to a webfont.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [webfont generator of Fontsquirre](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)l has a feature to subset a font, assuming you have the rights to upload and manipulate said font. Look under `Expert` options, then at `Subsetting` and pick accordingly.

Comment: Under `Expert > Subsetting > Custom > Unicode range` you should be able to define any kind of subset you need.